# Is this a good way of scoring?

Tags: java

I'm working on a program to test some things, but I can't figure it out.
I'm a total beginner and this is in pseudo-java. So not real java.

Just think as input that the user has to put in, and print as system.out.printl.

In a running competition there are 3 running clubs, each with 10 runners.

The numbers on the back of running club A are (from 700 until 709).

The numbers on the back of running club B are (from 800 until 809).

The numbers on the back of running club C are (from 900 until 909).

At the finish the numbers on the back are written down.
After the competition we get the list of all 30 numbers in order of finishing.
I'm designing a program that tells which club has won this competition.
(The club with the most numbers in the front of the list)

So far, I have this. But I'm not sure this is correct?
Is this way of scoring good?

Can anyone complete me? Or tell me where I am wrong? Or can tell me how do to it the correct way?
It would be much appreciated!

```
{
  // declaration

  // The points the clubs have
  int pointsClubA,pointsClubB,pointsClubC;
  // The runners that are finished
  int finished;
  // Position of the runner
  int position;
  // Het backnummer of the runner
  int backnummer;
  // Points being added to the clubs
  int points

  // De beginwaarden ingeven
  finished = 0;
  position = 1;
  points = 31;


  while (finished < 30)
  {
    print "What is the backnummer that just has finished";
    input backnummer;

    if (backnummer >= 700) && (backnummer < 710){
      pointsClubA = pointsClubA + points;
    }
    else if  ((backnummer >= 800) && (backnummer < 810)){
      pointsClubB = pointsClubB + points;
    } 
    else{
      pointsClubC = pointsClubC + points;
    } 
    print "On position nr",position,"its the runner with backnummer",backnummer,;

    position = position + 1;
    points = points -1;
    finished = finished + 1;

  } // End while module

  // Now the points calculate with club has won
  if (pointsClubA > pointsClubB) && (pointsClubA > pointsClubC){
    print "Club A has won";
  }
  if (pointsClubB > pointsClubA) && (pointsClubB > pointsClubC){
    print "Club B has won";
  }
  if ((pointsClubC > pointsClubA) && (pointsClubC > pointsClubB)){
    print "Club C is de winnaar";   
  }
} // end program
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about evaluating a scoring system.

Comment: http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_One_World_Championship_scoring_system - This is the scoring system of the formula one. I would just try to copy that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine. You will be able to achieve the objective.
Below approach is also similar with slight modifications.

**Note:** I assume that it is not a real-world case. If so, the system needs  to be designed more effectively. You might want to capture other details also and it would not make sense to ask user input the badge number every time. Also, with this approach, there is no way in which we are capturing the order of winners. It is fine for a simple assignment but not the right way for a real-world scenario.

```
int numberOfPlayers = 30;
int pointsClubA = 0, pointsClubB=0, pointsClubC=0;
String winner = "";

for (int i=0; i< numberOfPlayers ; i++)
{
    print "What is the number just finished?"
    input backnumber;

    if  (backnumber >=700 && backnumber <= 709)
    {
         pointsClubA++;
    }
    else  if  (backnumber >=800 && backnumber <= 809)
    {
         pointsClubB++;
    }
    else  if  (backnumber >=900 && backnumber <= 909)
    {
         pointsClubC++;
    }
    else
    {
         print ("invalid");
    }


   print "On position nr",(i+1),"its the runner with backnummer",backnumber,;
} // End of for loop

   int winningScore = Math.max (pointsClubA,pointsClubB, pointsClubC);

   if (pointsClubA == winningScore)
   {
       winner = "Team A"
   }  
   // Use if here instead of else if , because multiple winners are possible. 
   if (pointsClubB == winningScore)
   {
       if ("".equals(winner))
           winner = " and Team B"
       else
           winner = "Team B"
   }   
   if (pointsClubC == winningScore)
   {
       if ("".equals(winner))
           winner = " and Team C"
       else
           winner = "Team C"
   }           
   // Multiple winners are possible
   print "Match Won By : " +winner;

   // Sample outputs are:
   // Match won by Team A
   // Match won by Team B and Team C
```

Comment: @Durabrite: If it helped you, please accept as answer by clicking the grey tick mark by the side of this answer. Also, upvote once you have sufficient reputation. Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a fault here, all clubs seem to have 10points, because everyclub have 10 finished runners...

Comment: @Durabrite: You are right. Instead of `pointsClubA++`, you will have to put `pointsClubA = pointsClubA + (numberOfPlayers - i);` and similarly for club B and club C. Also in such case, I doubt if multiple winners are possible. so, you can use `else if` instead of `if` while forming the `winner` text.